# Filling NaN in DataFrame based on the values of a column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, nan

I have data that resembles the following simplified example:

```
Col1    Col2    Col3
a       A       10.1
b       A       NaN
d       B       NaN
e       B       12.3    
f       B       NaN
g       C       14.1
h       C       NaN
i       C       NaN
```

...for many thousands of rows.  I need to fillna based upon the value in Col2, using something analogous to the ffill method.  The result I'm looking for is this:

```
Col1    Col2    Col3
a       A       10.1
b       A       10.1
d       B       NaN
e       B       12.3    
f       B       12.3
g       C       14.1
h       C       14.1
i       C       14.1
```

However, this method ignores the value in Col2.  Any ideas?

Comment: It appears that Col1 is completely irrelevant, correct?  If not, please explain why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly then you can groupby on 'Col2' and then call transform on 'Col3' and call `ffill`:

```
In [35]:

df['Col3'] = df.groupby('Col2')['Col3'].transform(lambda x: x.ffill())
df
Out[35]:
  Col1 Col2  Col3
0    a    A  10.1
1    b    A  10.1
2    d    B   NaN
3    e    B  12.3
4    f    B  12.3
5    g    C  14.1
6    h    C  14.1
7    i    C  14.1
```

Comment: Hi Ed.  Note that the first B (index=2) should be a NaN, as it is the first value for 'B' and cannot be forward filled.

Comment: @Alexander no ffill going on here as the nan rows are dropped

Comment: @Alexander OK I see what you mean

Answer (score 1):

One answer I found is the following:

```
df['col3'] = df.groupby('Col2').transform('fillna',method='ffill')['col3']
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: I think you meant `df.groupby('Col2').transform('fillna',method='ffill')['Col3']`. Otherwise, it seems to work, but only for groups which are consecutive (which is either the question or not).

Comment: Agreed, I've edited the solution to reflect your comment.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np


df['Col3'] = np.where(df['Col2'] == 'A', df['Col3'].fillna(10.1), df["Col3"])
```

Of course replace accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

You can take slices of the DataFrame for each element of `Col2`, and then concatenate the results.

```
>>> pd.concat((df.loc[df.Col2 == letter, :].ffill() for letter in df.Col2.unique()))

  Col1 Col2  Col3
0    a    A  10.1
1    b    A  10.1
2    d    B   NaN
3    e    B  12.3
4    f    B  12.3
5    g    C  14.1
6    h    C  14.1
7    i    C  14.1
```

EDIT:  It appears the method presented by @EdChum is the fastest by far.

```
%timeit pd.concat((df.loc[df.Col2 == letter, :].ffill() for letter in df.Col2.unique()))
100 loops, best of 3: 3.57 ms per loop

%timeit df.groupby('Col2').transform('fillna',method='ffill')['Col3']
100 loops, best of 3: 4.59 ms per loop

%timeit df.groupby('Col2')['Col3'].transform(lambda x: x.ffill())
1000 loops, best of 3: 746 µs per loop
```